# Saving radio group checkedId with SharedPreferences to make the radio button selection to be the same when resuming Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, radio-button, sharedpreferences, radio-group

I'm trying to program an android app with android studio that counts steps taken by the user. I'm trying to make a settings/options activity where the user can both set their height and preferred measure unit. I was able to code the height selection so that it is saved into SharedPreferences so that every time the user returns to the settings activity the height stays the same.

I'm trying to do the same to the measure unit selection but it doesn't seem to work. I've put the measure unit selection into RadioButtons that are both in the same RadioGroup and I've managed to do so that the selected RadioButtonId is shown below. That way I was able to confirm that the code knows when I'm selecting a different button. But for some reason it doesn't save the selected Id or load it when returning to the settings activity.

I'm very new into all of this and I feel I've tried to search the solution everywhere before this. Hopefully you can help me to get past this!

Here is the settings xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".AsetuksetActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_asetukset"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/morrisromanalternate_black"
        android:text="Settings"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_distanceUnit"
        android:layout_width="170dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="90dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="200dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/morrisromanalternate_black"
        android:text="Measure Unit"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_asetukset" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_userHeight"
        android:layout_width="170dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="90dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="200dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/morrisromanalternate_black"
        android:text="Your Height"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_distanceUnit" />

    <NumberPicker
        android:id="@+id/user_height"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="19dp"
        android:theme="@style/number_picker_text"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/tv_ilmoitukset"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/tv_userHeight" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/heightUnitCm"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="28dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/morrisromanalternate_black"
        android:text="cm"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/tv_ilmoitukset"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/user_height" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_ilmoitukset"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/morrisromanalternate_black"
        android:text="Notifications"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="35sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_userHeight" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/test_textHeight"
        android:layout_width="280dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:text="Selected number"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_ilmoitukset" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/test_textUnit"
        android:layout_width="280dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="0"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="10sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/test_textHeight" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/koti_button"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:elevation="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/koti"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />


    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radio_group"
        android:layout_width="125dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/user_height"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/tv_distanceUnit">

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioBtn_km"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="@drawable/background"
            android:button="@android:color/transparent"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:fontFamily="@font/morrisromanalternate_black"
            android:text="km"
            android:textOff="km"
            android:textOn="km"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="@drawable/button_text_color"
            android:textSize="25sp"/>

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioBtn_mi"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="@drawable/background"
            android:button="@android:color/transparent"
            android:fontFamily="@font/morrisromanalternate_black"
            android:text="mi"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="@drawable/button_text_color"
            android:textOff="mi"
            android:textOn="mi"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"/>
    </RadioGroup>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

And here is the settings kotlin file:

```
    package com.example.stepstomountdoom

import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.widget.*
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity

class AsetuksetActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private var cm = 0
    private var unit = 0

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_asetukset)

        loadHeightData()
        loadUnitData()


        var button_settings = findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.koti_button)
        button_settings.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        }

        var test_textUnit = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.test_textUnit)
        var radio_group = findViewById<RadioGroup>(R.id.radio_group)
        var radioButton_km = findViewById<RadioButton>(R.id.radioBtn_km)
        var radioButton_mi = findViewById<RadioButton>(R.id.radioBtn_mi)

        radio_group.setOnCheckedChangeListener { radio_group, i ->
            if (radioButton_km.isChecked) {
                radioButton_km.id = radio_group.checkedRadioButtonId
            } else {
                radioButton_mi.id = radio_group.checkedRadioButtonId
            }
            test_textUnit.text = "${radio_group.checkedRadioButtonId}"
            unit = radio_group.checkedRadioButtonId
            saveUnitData()
        }

        val test_textHeight = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.test_textHeight)
        val user_height = findViewById<NumberPicker>(R.id.user_height)
        user_height.minValue = 0
        user_height.maxValue = 250
        user_height.wrapSelectorWheel = false

        user_height.setOnValueChangedListener { numberPicker, oldValue, newValue ->
            test_textHeight.text = "Selected number $newValue"
            cm = newValue
            saveHeightData()
        }
    }

    override fun onResume () {
        super.onResume()

        val user_height = findViewById<NumberPicker>(R.id.user_height)
        val radio_group = findViewById<RadioGroup>(R.id.radio_group)

        user_height.value = cm
        unit = radio_group.checkedRadioButtonId
    }

    private fun saveHeightData() {
        val sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("myPrefs",Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
        val editor = sharedPreferences.edit()
        editor.putFloat("key",cm.toFloat())
        editor.apply()
    }

    private fun loadHeightData() {
        val sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
        val savedNumber = sharedPreferences.getFloat("key", 0f)
        Log.d("AsetuksetActivity", "$savedNumber")
        cm = savedNumber.toInt()
    }

    private fun saveUnitData() {
        val sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
        val editor = sharedPreferences.edit()
        editor.putFloat("key2",unit.toFloat())
        editor.apply()
    }

    private fun loadUnitData() {
        val sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
        val savedId = sharedPreferences.getFloat("key2", 0f)
        Log.d("AsetuksetActivity","$savedId")
        unit = savedId.toInt()
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A number of things you can improve:

```
class AsetuksetActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

     companion object{
        /*
         *Values to be saved to preference. 
         *Saving the compiled id of a view is not safe 
         *as it can vary on different builds
         */
        private const val UNIT_KM = "km"
        private const val UNIT_MI = "mi"
     }

    private var cm = 0
    private var unit = "" //changed to string

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_asetukset)
          
        ...

        radio_group.setOnCheckedChangeListener { radio_group, i ->
                   
           /*
            if (radioButton_km.isChecked) {
                radioButton_km.id == radio_group.checkedRadioButtonId
            } else {
                radioButton_mi.id == radio_group.checkedRadioButtonId
            }
            test_textUnit.text = "${radio_group.checkedRadioButtonId}"
            radio_group.checkedRadioButtonId == unit
           */ 
           /*Note: Don't confuse equality operator == 
             with assignment operator =
            */     

           //should be 
           when(i){ //you can also use if else
                R.id.radioBtn_km -> unit = UNIT_KM 
                R.id.radioBtn_mi -> unit = UNIT_MI
           }
           test_textUnit.text = unit      
           saveUnitData()
        }

      ...
    }

    override fun onResume () {
        super.onResume()
         
        /*Consider using references of the ones declared in onCreate.
         *Make same references accessable by class members
         */ 
        val user_height = findViewById<NumberPicker>(R.id.user_height)
        val radio_group = findViewById<RadioGroup>(R.id.radio_group)

        user_height.value = cm

        //unit == radio_group.checkedRadioButtonId
        //should be 
        when (unit){
           UNIT_KM -> radio_group.check(R.id.radioBtn_km) 
           UNIT_MI -> radio_group.check(R.id.radioBtn_mi) 
        }
    }

   ... 

    private fun saveUnitData() {
        ...  
        //editor.putFloat("key2",unit.toFloat())

        //Will save String instead
        editor.putString("key2",unit)
        editor.apply()
    }

    private fun loadUnitData() {
        val sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
        /*val savedId = sharedPreferences.getFloat("key2", 0f)
          unit = savedId.toInt()
        Log.d("AsetuksetActivity","$savedId")*/
        
        unit = sharedPreferences.getString("key2", "")
        Log.d("AsetuksetActivity", unit)
   
    }

}
```

Comment: Super! Thank you so much! This works and solves the problem. And also teaches new things about how to use a when statement and Ints, Floats and Strings.

Answer (score 0):

change

```
radio_group.checkedRadioButtonId == unit
```

to

```
radio_group.checkedRadioButtonId = unit
```

Besides, you're storing RadioButtonId

```
unit = radio_group.checkedRadioButtonId
```

try storing an Int instead of RadioButtonId, i parameter returns an indication for the selected radio button:

```
 radio_group.setOnCheckedChangeListener { radio_group, i ->
            ...
            unit = i
            saveUnitData()
        }
```

```
editor.putInt("key2",unit.toInt())
```

Comment: Thank you! I fixed it and added

test_textUnit.text = "${radio_group.checkedRadioButtonId}" 

to the override fun onResume () { part but when I return to the settings activity it just returns a value -1 instead of any of the two values it had previously given to the RadioButton options. It's as if it either didn't save or load the value at all, as far as I understand.

Comment: I've updated. Let me know if it worked

Comment: pls upvote the answer if it was useful

Answer (score 0):

Your radio button listener has things backwards:

```
radio_group.checkedRadioButtonId == unit
```

It should be

```
unit = radio_group.checkedRadioButtonId
```

so you're storing the current value in `unit`, and then saving it. What you were actually doing is *comparing* `unit` to the ID, using `==`.

Comment: Thank you! I fixed it and added 

test_textUnit.text = "${radio_group.checkedRadioButtonId}"

to the override fun onResume () { part

but when I return to the settings activity it just returns a value -1 instead of any of the two values it had previously given to the RadioButton options. It's as if it either didn't save or load the value at all, as far as I understand.

Comment: @Tuomas your `onResume` code is backwards too, you're doing `unit = radio_group.checkedRadioButtonId` (store the ID of the current checked button in `unit`, `-1` if nothing's checked yet e.g. at startup) instead of `radio_group.check(unit)` (check the appropriate button to match the stored value). When you *store* the current ID you need to *read* it from the radio group. When you *restore* the current ID you need to *set* it on the radio group

Comment: You're basically loading the stored value (to `unit`) in `onCreate`, then in `onResume` you're wiping that value and replacing it with the ID of whatever's currently checked in the `RadioGroup`, which at that point is nothing (unless you've set a default in the XML). `-1` means nothing is checked: https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/widget/RadioGroup?hl=en#getcheckedradiobuttonid - so instead of applying your saved state to the uninitialised `RadioGroup`, you're replacing it with that uninitialised state